# Wrapper Service in Linux

Tags: java, linux, debian

I am new to Linux,I need help on the following..

My application has been running in windows as a service using wrapper for a quite long period and now I want to bring it on Debian OS. After googled for a while,I find wrapper package for linux environment too,and tried installed the testWrapper comes along with the wrapper Package, and I can see the installed stuff under etc/init.d directory, but when I tried to start the service it reports me a error as follows **"wrapper: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected"**,.
the command which i used to install is **sudo sh testWrapper install**
and for starting is **sudo sh testWrapper start** 
and for the clarification of you guys, I don't have any missing parantheses in the wrapper.conf
 please help me out on this..

Thanks in Advance

Kallathiyan

Comment: rather than a missing parenthesis, it looks like an **extra** parenthesis the problem.

Comment: please post the produced init.d script

Comment: @matt: Thanks matt, the thing is i'm using the wrapper.conf file for configuration and testWrapper as the shell script comes along with the wrapper package and i do just modifications on top of the given file

Comment: @aleedam: thanks aleadam, i'm sure it is something i'm doing wrong  with configuration, not about missing or extra parantheses..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service wrapper of choice for CollabNet Subversion Edge I chose was based on the Java Service Wrapper from tanukisoftware as it is open-source and well documented... http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/launch-nix.html. Download the community edition if your software is open-source or buy their license.

In order to debug this error, first try to get the service running without anything configured... the current version of the published Subversion Edge that runs on Ubuntu without a problem.

Subversion Edge open-source version has its pre-configured version located [here](https://ctf.open.collab.net/integration/viewvc/viewvc.cgi/trunk/console/csvn-service-wrapper/linux/?root=svnedge&system=exsy1005). The good news is that if you provide your software as download, you can package this Wrapper in a way that users can just install the service... For instance, running the command "csvn" without any parameter from the "bin" directory in the given directory "CSVN_HOME" will show the available commands...

```
$ cd CSVN_HOME/bin
$ csvn
Usage: ./csvn { console | start | stop | restart | condrestart | status | install | remove | dump }
```

Users can then install the service by just running the command with the "install" parameter or simply "start", which will install the scripts under /etc/init.d... (with sudo for that matter) or if the user just want to run the application they can just use "console".

Comment: Thanks for your answer: I followed the same using wrapper in ubuntu and now i am getting the different error as follows: wrapper: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")"),

Answer (score 1):

Kallathiyan,
Is this error happening prior to the Wrapper itself being launched?  Do you see the Wrapper's version banner?  My guess is that this is a problem in the shell script.

Please make sure that the shell script has been transferred to your Debian system with UNIX line feeds.  A common problem is to have Windows line feeds in the shell script so it can't be parsed correctly.

Cheers,
Leif

Comment: Hey Thanks Leif, I got solved my problem, it's something went wrong in Wrapper Package, I have got the 3.5.8 release from wrapper and now it's doing fine.